# cannot get values from mapStateToProps on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Why I cannot access `descriptionList` from `mapStateToProps` is kind of weird cause I called the action `fetchDescription` but I'm not sure why is returning undefined `descriptionList` in the component

here is the console.log showing that the list is there:

[image]

This is my component:

import { fetchDescription } from '../../actions/actions';

```
const Description = (props) => {
const { descriptionList } = props;
 useEffect(() => { 
     props.fetchDescription();
     console.log("Prop", descriptionList) // return undefined
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            {descriptionList}
        </div>
    );
};

  const mapStateToProps = ({descriptionList}) => {

    console.log("mapStateToProps", descriptionList)
    return descriptionList
  };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchDescription })(Description);
```

Comment: have you tried using Redux Hooks inside functional components ?

its much simpler and works same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is with iteration of result:

```
{
    return props.descriptionList.map(descriptionLi => {
      return (
        <div className="item" key={descriptionLi.id}>
          <div className="content">
            {descriptionLi.title}
            <div className="description">{descriptionLi.description}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

and on mapStateToProps try something like `Object.value` to get an array that can be iterable with `.map`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { descriptionList: Object.values(state.descriptionList) };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchDescription }
)(Description);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mapStateToProps function should return a plain object that contains the data the component needs.

try in next way:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({descriptionList}) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps", descriptionList)
    return { descriptionList };
  };
```

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Comment: I forgot to add as object, this is my initial code:  `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { descriptionList: state. descriptionList  };` I've added in that way just to console log the result. But is retuning the initial state and the `descriptionList` is now just empty. ;|